# save data to Parse cloud

Tags: android, cloud, parse-platform

I have 3 edit-texts in my activity (Name, mobile number, occupation) and a button (Save). I want to save these three data to Parse-cloud every-time when user clicks on the button.
Then new activity to display with a image in imageview that should be saved with the corresponding mobile number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Saving data to parse is very simple. In your button click handler you just need to get the 3 values that you are interested in then create the new parse object;

```
String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
String mobileNumber = mobileNumberEditText.getText().toString();
String occupation = occupationEditText.getText().toString();

ParseObject dataObject = new ParseObject();
dataObject.put("name", name);
dataObject.put("mobilenumber", mobileNumber);
dataObject.put("occupation", occupation);
dataObject.saveInBackground();
```

Somewhere in your app you will need to remember to set your application id and key as supplied to you by Parse. I tend to do it in an `Application` object in the `onCreate` method;

```
public void onCreate() {
    Parse.initialize(this, "Your Application Id", "Your Client Key");
}
```

The [Parse Object API](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects) is very simple to work with I tend to find as there isn't too much to get your head around. If you are completely new to Parse and you haven't already then I would recommend taking a look at their [quickstart](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#android/native/existing).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. However, I'm still facing problem if u cud help on that as well